# Why does a DLL compiled in MinGW crash?

Tags: dll, cygwin, mingw, libstdc++, g++-4.7

I have compiled one DLL in Cygwin using g++ 4.7. It works fine. But when I compile same code in MinGW and try to use a DLL. It crashes the program with access denied (CX00000005) error and shows libstdc++-6.dll as problem DLL.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing a MinGW dll or have a cygwin dll in PATH when you run your application. Be sure to copy the correct dll's to the same directory as your exe.

Comment: Thanks @rubenvb, I have taken care of such things. I removed all cygwin paths form PATH environment variable and copied all dlls from MinGW only. But problem still exists.

Comment: Run it through Dependency Walker (to be absolutely certain which DLLs are used) and a debugger to see where the problem may lie.

Comment: I resolved the problem by downgrading gcc to 4.6.2 from 4.7.2. It was a gcc [bug 55171](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55171) causing my dll crash.